# Can I use a computed column in a table to fetch data from another table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables : a) BookFine and b) IssuedBook.

In BookFine, I have the columns RegNo and LateFee where I am storing just the Late Fees of delayed 
Books against the Registration Number of Student.

In IssuedBook I have the columns RegNo,
BookTitle, IssueDate and ReturnDate.

I want to achieve this thing involving both tables :

> Whenever a student delays a book after the ReturnDate ( Like if
>   ReturnDate < Current Date ) then the LateFee Column in BookFine table
>   should be incremented by 1 where BookFine.RegNo = IssuedBook.RegNo.

I have successfully done this through SQL Job Schedules but I wonder if this is the way it should be done or is there any other good way of doing it. Note that I am using SQL Server 2008 r2.

Thanks.

Comment: No. [A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other columns in the same table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You could manage this with a trigger, but if it is a computed value, I'd be inclined to just create a view that includes a column with the definition you wanted to use for the computed column.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to write a script that could be run nightly that "increments BookFine by 1"  Is that the case?  How do you know if a book is returned or still checked out?

Comment: thanks for this rapid response anyway. I had mistakenly written the question title wrong. I noticed it later.

Comment: if the book has been returned the row related to that book would be deleted from the IssuedBook table. If it remains there then more latefee would be added as long as it is there after it is delayed

Comment: You might find it easier to just not have the BookFine table at all, it could just be a view.  CREATE VIEW BookFine AS SELECT RegNo, DATEDIFF(day,ReturnDate,getDate()) as LateFee WHERE ReturnDate < CurrentDate   This is more reliable than a nightly script.

Comment: would it be possible to fetch the late fee against a registration number later from the View through select statement...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
UPDATE BookFine 
   SET LateFee = LateFee +1
 WHERE RegNo IN (SELECT RegNo FROM IssuedBook WHERE ReturnDate < CurrentDate)
```

But you need to handle cases like if there are no records for this student in BookFine, this could be done by first running a prep statement to initialize a zero record. (Putting both of these in a transaction would prevent stray 0 records from being made)

```
INSERT INTO BookFine (RegNo, LateFee)
SELECT RegNo, 0
  FROM IssuedBook
 WHERE ReturnDate < CurrentDate
   AND RegNo NOT IN (SELECT RegNo FROM BookFine)
```